# How can I specify this relation using active record?

Tags: activerecord, yii, relationship

I am verymuch confused with the `through` relations. Here are my tables

batch (id,name)

subject(id,batch_id,name)

teacher(id,name)

subject_teacher(subject_id,teacher_id)

the relations are

batch HAS_MANY subjects

subjects BELONGS_TO batch

subject MANY_MANY teachers via subject_teacher

teachers MANY_MANY subjects via subject_teacher

No how can i specify the relation for getting

1. Teachers of a batch
2. Batches assigned for a teacher

i tried with a [through](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHasManyRelation#through-detail) option but it not seems to work with MANY_MANY relations. Is there any better way other than iterating through each subject?

EDIT:
I know I can get the subjects of a teacher by the function in Teacher model

```
public function getBatches()
{
    $batches=array();
    foreach($this->subjects as $subject)
        $batches[]=$subject->batch;
    return $batches;
}
```

now I can get batches of a teacher by referring `$teacher->batches`. But I need a cleaner relation like solution so that some where in the code I can make a statement like `Teacher::model()->with('batches')->findAll()`

Answer (score 0):

I think it is the only way to loop through the subjects. unless you don't do it through the active record.

```
  //pseudo code....
  Teacher=new Teacher::model()->with('subject.batch')->find();
  subjects=Teacher->subjects;
  for(subjects as subject){
      batch=subejct->batch;
  }
```

The through relationship can only be applied in one-many or one-one cases, not many-many.

Comment: the problem with this solution is that we cant use any with('batches') for eager loading and i think it will cause many queries to be executed

Comment: it doesnt work. Since there is no 'subject' in Teacher model. It is 'subjects'. So we cant use 'subject.batch' in with()

Comment: I think, it does not differ, try to use subjects.batch, because it is the relationship, not the objects, so it does not matter if it is singular or plural..but let me know if it works :)

Comment: You probably need to add a together() chain too.